# Zugang "auf" vs "zu"

Tags: grammatical-case

Was ist die richtige Präposition, ich suche [in](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=zugang%20zu%20&cw=546) und [hier](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/zugang+auf+die+webseite.html?cw=546) aber  finde, die Beide sind richtig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Janka hat eigentlich schon das meiste gesagt, aber deinem Kommentar zufolge hast du immernoch Schwierigkeiten mit den Präpositionen. Ich versuche daher, es nochmal einfacher und deutlicher zu machen:

Wenn man 'Zugang' durch 'Ich gehe' ersetzt ist es vielleicht einfacher:

> Ich gehe zum Parkplatz
>   Ich gehe zum Baum

'Zum/zu/zur' steht dafür wenn man sich zu etwas hinbewegt, bzw. sich etwas nähert. Genau genommen ist "Ich gehe zum Parkplatz" und "Ich gehe auf den Parkplatz" auch nicht das selbe, da das eine bedeutet, dass man sich darauf zubewegt und das andere, dass man das Ziel hat den Parkplatz zu betreten. Da "Zugang" jedoch auch bedeutet, etwas zu betreten fällt hier der Unterschied weg.

Deutsch ist jedoch sehr inkonsequent was die Präpositionen angeht, da

- wir gehen zur Schule
- wir gehen in die Schule
- wir gehen auf die Schule

alles das gleiche bedeuten kann.

Generell hat 'Zugang zu' zwei Bedeutungen:
1.)
Zugang im Sinne von Eingang, bzw. die Möglichkeit mit welcher man in/auf/zu einem bestimmten Ort kommt.

> Zugang/Eingang zum Haus/zur Straße/zum Zoo/zum Museum

Hierbei kann man das 'zu' durch andere Präpositionen ersetzen(in das Haus, auf die Straße, in das Museum).

2.)
Zugang im Sinne von Erlaubnis/Möglichkeit, das heißt, dass man das Recht hat, etwas zu betreten.

> Mit meinem Ticket habe ich Zugang zum Zoo -> Ich darf in den Zoo
>   Als Anwohner habe ich Zugang zum Parkhaus -> Ich kann in das Parkhaus
>   Die Einladung gibt mir Zugang zu der Feier -> Ich darf zur Feier

Bei dieser Bedeutung kann das 'zu' nicht ersetzt werden. In deinen Beispielen ist beides mal diese Bedeutung gemeint.

Comment: bedeutet zu, in, auf im ersten Fall  bei dem Ort vorbeikommen und nicht im dem Ort sein können ?

Comment: Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob ich deine Frage richtig verstehe, aber im ersten Fall bedeutet Zugang zu Dinge wie zum Beipiel eine Tür, die der Zugang zum Haus ist. Falls du meinen ersten Satz meinst, dann bedeutet "ich gehe zu [...]" sinngemäß "ich nähere mich [...]"

Answer (score 3):

Wenn das Wort *Zugang* einen *Gang* beschreiben soll, durch den man *auf einen Platz* kommt, kann man beide Präpositionen synonym verwenden:

> Zugang zum Parkplatz/zum Markt/zur Webseite
>
> Zugang auf den Parkplatz/auf den Markt/auf die Webseite

Das funktioniert nicht mehr, wenn der Ort kein Platz ist, *auf* dem man sich befinden kann. Dort muss man dann die passende Präposition verwenden:

> Zugang zum Haus
>
> <s>Zugang auf das Haus</s> *(außer in manchen Dialekten)*
>
> Zugang in das Haus

Es funktioniert ebenfalls nicht, wenn der *Zugang* im übertragenen Sinne gemeint ist:

> Zugang zu Alkohol und Drogen

Comment: was ist der Unterschied hier zwischen (Zugang auf den Markt)und(Zugang aufs Haus) die beide sind Orten

Comment: Die Präposition *in* meint, dass man in einem Objekt drin ist. Ein Haus hat Wände, einen Boden und ein Dach, man kann also *in* einem Haus sein. Man kann auch *auf* einem Haus sein, in den meisten Dialekten heißt das aber, dass man oben *auf* dem Dach des Hauses sitzt. Umgekehrt kann man nicht *in* einem Platz sein, weil der Platz keine Wände hat. Bei manchen Orten, z.B. dem Hof, kommt es auf den Dialekt an: Norddeutsch *auf dem Hof*, aber Süddeutsch *im Hof*. Das hängt wohl damit zusammen, dass im süddeutschen Gebiet Bauernhöfe häufiger Wände rundherum hatten.