# Warum heißt es "ich fahre an die Grenze" oder "ich fahre zu der Grenze"?

Tags: grammaticality

Welche Grammatik-Regel ist dafür verantwortlich? Weil es ja `die Grenze` ist.

Comment: Wie sollte es anders heißen / in welchem Kontext stellt sich die Frage? In beiden gefragten Bsp. ist `Grenze` weiblich, also sehe ich keinen Widerspruch.

Comment: Ein Freund hat mir geschrieben `Ich fahre zu die Grenze.` und ich würde ihm gerne sagen warum das falsch ist.

Comment: hm, ich bin verwirrt, dass die Frage lautet "warum ist sorum richtig", um dann später erklären zu können "darum ist andersrum falsch". Die Kommentare soweit vollständig: die Deklination und Fälle erfordern das, das eigentliche Zitat ist wahlweise Dialekt (mein Verdacht: Ruhrpott) oder falsches Deutsch.

Comment: maybe related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49747/zugang-auf-vs-zu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Ich fahre *zu* der Grenze.
- Ich fahre *an* die Grenze.

Zunächst einmal: beides ist richtig und bedeutet inhaltlich das gleiche.

Warum heißt es einmal *die Grenze* und ein anderes Mal *der Grenze*? Das liegt an den unterschiedlichen Präpositionen *zu* und *an*, die jeweils mit einem anderen Kasus (grammatischer Fall) verwendet werden. Die vier Fälle für das weibliche Wort *Grenze* sind:

> - die Grenze **(Nominativ)**
> - (wegen) der Grenze **(Genitiv)**
> - (zu) der Grenze **(Dativ)**
> - (an) die Grenze **(Akkusativ)**

Comment: @IQV Au ja, danke. Sie dürfen sowas natürlich auch selber korrigieren.

Comment: Wobei "an die Grenze gehen" eine besondere Bedeutung hat, und "Zur (= zu der) Grenze gehen" ist nicht äquivalent.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Richtig, aber um diese Bedeutung geht es hier nicht. Der OP hat explizit nach _an die Grenze **fahren**_ gefragt, was nicht dieselbe Sonderbedeutung wie _an die Grenze **gehen**_ hat.

Comment: @Björn: Weiß ich. Wollte nur darauf hinweisen, dass das nicht immer gilt.

Answer (score 1):

Es heißt "zu **der** Grenze", weil das ein Dativ nach "zu" ist. Es heißt "an **die** Grenze", weil das ein Akkusativ nach "an" ist.

Die Grenze (Nominativ)
Der Grenze (Genitiv)
Der Grenze (Dativ)
Die Grenze (Akkusativ)